# How to conditionally fill in rows with NAs depending on an evaluation of the first two columns in a dataframe using R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Metric = c('WI', NA, 'MN', NA, 'CO', NA),
  Eval = c('WI', NA, 'AK', NA, 'CO', NA),
  colA = c(30, 'ABC', 45, 'DEF', 2, 'XYZ'),
  colB = c(25, 'BEC', 23, 'FED', 50, 'HIJ')
)
```

I'd like to evaluate whether the `Metric` column and the `Eval` column are equal, and, if they are, fill everything to the right of the `Metric` column with NAs so the result would look like this:

```
df_desired <- data.frame(
  Metric = c('WI', NA, 'MN', NA, 'CO', NA),
  Eval = c(NA, NA, 'AK', NA, NA, NA),
  colA = c(NA, 'ABC', 45, 'DEF', NA, 'XYZ'),
  colB = c(NA, 'BEC', 23, 'FED', NA, 'HIJ')
)
```

What's the best way to do this using R, ideally with a `tidyverse` function? I tried using `mutate`/`across`, but defining the conditional here is throwing me off.

Answer (score 1):

Create a logical vector and do the assignment based on row/column index/names (`base R` is more direct to do)

```
i1 <- with(df, Metric == Eval & !is.na(Metric) & !is.na(Eval))
df[i1, -1] <- NA
```

-output

```
> df
  Metric Eval colA colB
1     WI <NA> <NA> <NA>
2   <NA> <NA>  ABC  BEC
3     MN   AK   45   23
4   <NA> <NA>  DEF  FED
5     CO <NA> <NA> <NA>
6   <NA> <NA>  XYZ  HIJ
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, create a column of logical vector ('i1'), loop `across` the columns 'Eval' to 'colB', use `case_when/ifelse/if_else/replace` to change the values to `NA` based on the 'i1' and remove the temporary column by assigning to `NULL`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(i1 = Metric == Eval, 
    across(Eval:colB, ~ case_when(i1 ~ NA_character_, TRUE ~ .)), 
      i1 = NULL)
```

-output

```
 Metric Eval colA colB
1     WI <NA> <NA> <NA>
2   <NA> <NA>  ABC  BEC
3     MN   AK   45   23
4   <NA> <NA>  DEF  FED
5     CO <NA> <NA> <NA>
6   <NA> <NA>  XYZ  HIJ
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mutate()` and `if_else()` to conditionally replace values:

```r
df |>
  mutate(colA = if_else(Metric == Eval, NA_character_, colA, missing = colA))
#>   Metric Eval colA colB
#> 1     WI   WI <NA>   25
#> 2   <NA> <NA>  ABC  BEC
#> 3     MN   AK   45   23
#> 4   <NA> <NA>  DEF  FED
#> 5     CO   CO <NA>   50
#> 6   <NA> <NA>  XYZ  HIJ
```

Note that we can't just use `NA`, we have to match it to the existing column type. In your example `colA` and `colB` are character vectors, so it's `NA_character_`. And we have to specify `missing` to handle the `NA == NA` case.

To generalise this across multiple columns, use `across()` and wrap the `if_else()` in an anonymous function:

```r
df |>
  mutate(across(Eval:colB, ~if_else(Metric == Eval, NA_character_, ., missing = .)))
#>   Metric Eval colA colB
#> 1     WI <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 2   <NA> <NA>  ABC  BEC
#> 3     MN   AK   45   23
#> 4   <NA> <NA>  DEF  FED
#> 5     CO <NA> <NA> <NA>
#> 6   <NA> <NA>  XYZ  HIJ
```